# Using AWK find a smallest number in a second column bigger than x

Tags: bash, scripting, sed, awk

I have a file with two columns,

```
sdfsd 1.3
sdfds 3
sdfsdf 2.1
dsfsdf -1
```

if x is 2

I want to print sdfsdf 2.1

How to express it in awk  (bash or sed is fine too)

Answer (score 3):

It's awfully tempting to do this:

```
sort -k 2 -g  | awk '$2 >= 2 { print; exit }'
```

Tested and works on your example.  If no second column is at least 2, it prints nothing.

Comment: don't forget to pass the input file to sort

Answer (score 1):

awk:

```
BEGIN {
  min=0
  mint=""
  threshold=2
}
{
  if($2 > threshold && ($2 < min || min == 0)) {
    min = $2
    mint = $1
  }
}
END
{
  print mint, min
}
```

Comment: Output is zero if threshold is the same as the max value. It should probably output an error.